# Bundling of .d.ts declarations of external modules

Tags: typescript, webpack, rollupjs, typescript-declarations

My intention is to bundle TypeScript definitions of TS code written by myself with definitions of external modules residing in node_modules. The reasoning behind is that I need to supply these joint definitions to a web-based TS code editor ([MonacoEditor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/)) to allow for code completion.

So far I have gotten some things to work with [rollup-plugin-ts](https://github.com/wessberg/rollup-plugin-ts) and have also asked the question below in the [rollup-plugin-ts github issue #164](https://github.com/wessberg/rollup-plugin-ts/issues/164), so far without any answer. I have also experimented with rollup-plugin-dts, but couldn't get it to work any better. I am however open to the choice of framework (doesn't need to be rollup), I just need definitions of custom code, node-internal modules and external modules to be bundled into a **single** .d.ts file that only exports what the entry point .ts file exported.

What I have working quite well:

- Transpiling .ts to .js and bundling into a single .js file (note: I don't need the .js file; in the end I would turn on emitDeclarationOnly, but this isn't too relevant now). This is working for custom code, node-internal modules (such as 'path') and external modules (such as 'typeorm')
- Transpiling .ts to .d.ts **only** for custom code

What isn't working yet:

- Transpiling .ts to .d.ts for node-internal and external modules only references the modules **but I would like to have them inlined in the same .d.ts file**

**Now is there any way how I can force rollup-plugin-ts (or use any other tool) to inline external type definitions as well?**

For reference, I have created the following minimal repo, including the output .js and .d.ts: https://github.com/sumbricht/rollup_dts_example. In reality it would include definitions for around 100 external modules, therefore manually managing wouldn't be feasible; alternative automatable approaches are however also welcome :-).

Below the main files:
**rollup.config.js:**

```js
import ts from 'rollup-plugin-ts'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import polyfill from 'rollup-plugin-polyfill-node'

const config = [
    {
        input: "./src/entrypoint.ts",
        output: [{ file: "./dist/entrypoint.js", format: "es" }],
        plugins: [
            polyfill(),
            commonjs(),
            nodeResolve(),
            ts({
                tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
                exclude: [],
            })
        ],
    },
];

export default config;
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "ESNext",

    /* Modules */
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["node"],

    /* Emit */
    "declaration": true,
  },
  "exclude": []
}
```

**entrypoint.ts:**

```js
// code by myself: nicely reflected in .js and .d.ts
export { Foo } from './foo'

// node-internal code: nicely reflected in .js but as external reference in .d.ts
export { dirname } from 'path'

// external module: nicely reflected in .js but as external reference in .d.ts
export { createConnection } from 'typeorm'
```

**entrypoint.js:**

```js
class Foo {
    foo;
    constructor(foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    printFoo() {
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
}

// code from 'path' and 'typeorm' (cut for brevity)

export { Foo, createConnection$1 as createConnection, dirname };
```

**entrypoint.d.ts:**

```js
declare class Foo {
    private foo;
    constructor(foo: string);
    printFoo(): void;
}
export { Foo };
export { dirname } from 'path';
export { createConnection } from 'typeorm';
```

Comment: Did you figured this out? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty similar use case. You might want to check out the `tsup` with `--dts-resolve` option. It allows you to resolve and bundle external types into a single `.d.ts` file. You can add the `--dts-only` option if you want `.d.ts` file only.

The [official docs](https://tsup.egoist.dev/#generate-declaration-file) doesn't have much of information about it, but [this blog](https://dev.to/egoist/rollup-dts-file-using-tsup-2579) can give you an idea.